# Install Google Chrome on 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I'm trying to install Google Chrome in my Ubuntu 11.10 OS however I'm getting this error:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for xybrek: 
Selecting previously deselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 167351 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (from google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on gconf-service; however:
  Package gconf-service is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 2.31.1); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1); however:
  Version of libx11-6 on system is 2:1.4.4-2ubuntu1.
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: You may get more answers if you Chang the title to explain the problem is installing chrome. On 11.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is due to the fact that the software repositories for 11.10 do not have those packages (gconf-service, libgconf-2-4, libx11-6 >= 2:1.4.99.1). For this reason, the software package is not installable on 11.10. Releases from 12.04 onwards should work.

Comment: For the Ubuntu equivalent of Google Chrome, try Chromium (package `chromium-browser`). They're pretty much exactly the same.

Comment: Problem here is that I'm not sure if the Chrome plugins I will be needing that work for Chrome would work for Chromium out of the box

Comment: Most Chrome extensions will also work on Chromium. Chromium is basically an open-source fork of Chrome authored by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Please look here: http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.in/2013/06/stable-channel-update_17.html

To quote:

```
The Stable channel has been updated to 28.0.1500.45 for Linux.

The minimum requirements for Linux have also been updated:

Ubuntu 12.04+
Debian 7+
OpenSuSE 12.2+
Fedora Linux 17+
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but can you site some solution other than upgrading to 12.04

Answer (score 0):

This is happen just because of dependencies,

Try fallowing command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I've tried this already, but it did not help...

Comment: http://ilostmynotes.blogspot.com/2012/11/solved-dependency-problems-prevent.html - This post might be help you. It could happen with some third party tools so try to remove them or try `sudo apt-get autoremove` as the first step.